# Can I call the function like that?

Tags: c++

If I have a struct.

```
struct studentRec  
{
    string name;
    int sid;
    string major;
    int cohort;
};
```

Then, I have a function.

```
int compare_MajorName(const studentRec& s1, const studentRec& s2)
```

Can I call the function like that?

```
String major = ECE;
list = new studentRec[n];
compare_MajorName(list[mid], major)
```

Comment: what is `list`? what is `String`? Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: no, String is not a studentRec

Comment: Note that `c++` is case sensitive. Not sure if `String` is just a typo or your using some code that has a `String` class or that you are not even using `c++` instead using `c++-cli`

Comment: Why do you think that you possibly could? Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: See also `std::vector<studentRec>`.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

Your function parameters require `studentRec`s. A `String` cannot be converted to a `studentRec` automagically. It wouldn't make sense.

You have two possibilities:

- make an overrided function which accepts a `String` as a second parameter
- simply compare the name inside the struct with your `String`:
  `list[mid].name == major` for exemple